# I'm trying to use touch in a JavaScript web application, but I am stuck on a detail

Tags: javascript, web-applications, touch

I'm trying to make JavaScript game. I started following a tutorial, but now I'm going to do it for mobile and for some reason I can't change the movement of the player from the keys to touch. I've even tried chatGPT, but even it didn't help me. My code has this part commented in English, because I'm learning the language and part of it is in Portuguese because I'm Brazilian.

```
var DIRECTION = {
    IDLE: 0,
    UP: 1,
    DOWN: 2,
    LEFT: 3,
    RIGHT: 4
};
 
var rounds = [5, 5, 3, 3, 2];
var colors = ['#1abc9c', '#2ecc71', '#3498db', '#8c52ff', '#9b59b6'];
 
// The ball object (The cube that bounces back and forth)
var Ball = {
    new: function (incrementedSpeed) {
        return {
            width: 18,
            height: 18,
            x: (this.canvas.width / 2) - 9, 
            y: (this.canvas.height / 2) - 9,
            moveX: DIRECTION.IDLE,
            moveY: DIRECTION.IDLE,
            speed: incrementedSpeed || 7 
        };
    }
};
 
// The ai object (The two lines that move up and down)
var Ai = {
    new: function (side) {
        return {
            width: 18,
            height: 180,
            x: side === 'left' ? 150 : this.canvas.width - 150,
            y: (this.canvas.height / 2) - 35,
            score: 0,
            move: DIRECTION.IDLE,
            speed: 8
        };
    }
};
 
var Game = {
    initialize: function () {
        this.canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
 
        this.canvas.width = 1400;
        this.canvas.height = 1000;
 
        this.canvas.style.width = (this.canvas.width / 2) + 'px';
        this.canvas.style.height = (this.canvas.height / 2) + 'px';
 
        this.player = Ai.new.call(this, 'left');
        this.ai = Ai.new.call(this, 'right');
        this.ball = Ball.new.call(this);
 
        this.ai.speed = 5;
        this.running = this.over = false;
        this.turn = this.ai;
        this.timer = this.round = 0;
        this.color = '#8c52ff';
 
        Pong.menu();
        Pong.listen();
    },
 
    endGameMenu: function (text) {
        // Change the canvas font size and color
        Pong.context.font = '45px Courier New';
        Pong.context.fillStyle = this.color;
 
        // Draw the rectangle behind the 'Press any key to begin' text.
        Pong.context.fillRect(
            Pong.canvas.width / 2 - 350,
            Pong.canvas.height / 2 - 48,
            700,
            100
        );
 
        // Change the canvas color;
        Pong.context.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
 
        // Draw the end game menu text ('Game Over' and 'Winner')
        Pong.context.fillText(text,
            Pong.canvas.width / 2,
            Pong.canvas.height / 2 + 15
        );
 
        setTimeout(function () {
            Pong = Object.assign({}, Game);
            Pong.initialize();
        }, 3000);
    },
 
    menu: function () {
        // Draw all the Pong objects in their current state
        Pong.draw();
 
        // Change the canvas font size and color
        this.context.font = '50px Courier New';
        this.context.fillStyle = this.color;
 
        // Draw the rectangle behind the 'Press any key to begin' text.
        this.context.fillRect(
            this.canvas.width / 2 - 350,
            this.canvas.height / 2 - 48,
            700,
            100
        );
 
        // Change the canvas color;
        this.context.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
 
        // Draw the 'press any key to begin' text
        this.context.fillText('Tecle para começar ',
            this.canvas.width / 2,
            this.canvas.height / 2 + 15
        );
    },
 
    // Update all objects (move the player, ai, ball, increment the score, etc.)
    update: function () {
        if (!this.over) {
            // If the ball collides with the bound limits - correct the x and y coords.
            if (this.ball.x <= 0) Pong._resetTurn.call(this, this.ai, this.player);
            if (this.ball.x >= this.canvas.width - this.ball.width) Pong._resetTurn.call(this, this.player, this.ai);
            if (this.ball.y <= 0) this.ball.moveY = DIRECTION.DOWN;
            if (this.ball.y >= this.canvas.height - this.ball.height) this.ball.moveY = DIRECTION.UP;

            // On new serve (start of each turn) move the ball to the correct side
            // and randomize the direction to add some challenge.
            if (Pong._turnDelayIsOver.call(this) && this.turn) {
                this.ball.moveX = this.turn === this.player ? DIRECTION.LEFT : DIRECTION.RIGHT;
                this.ball.moveY = [DIRECTION.UP, DIRECTION.DOWN][Math.round(Math.random())];
                this.ball.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.canvas.height - 200) + 200;
                this.turn = null;
            }
 
            // If the player collides with the bound limits, update the x and y coords.
            if (this.player.y <= 0) this.player.y = 0;
            else if (this.player.y >= (this.canvas.height - this.player.height)) this.player.y = (this.canvas.height - this.player.height);
            // Move ball in intended direction based on moveY and moveX values
            if (this.ball.moveY === DIRECTION.UP) this.ball.y -= (this.ball.speed / 1.5);
            else if (this.ball.moveY === DIRECTION.DOWN) this.ball.y += (this.ball.speed / 1.5);
            if (this.ball.moveX === DIRECTION.LEFT) this.ball.x -= this.ball.speed;
            else if (this.ball.moveX === DIRECTION.RIGHT) this.ball.x += this.ball.speed;
 
            // Handle ai (AI) UP and DOWN movement
            if (this.ai.y > this.ball.y - (this.ai.height / 2)) {
                if (this.ball.moveX === DIRECTION.RIGHT) this.ai.y -= this.ai.speed / 1.5;
                else this.ai.y -= this.ai.speed / 4;
            }
            if (this.ai.y < this.ball.y - (this.ai.height / 2)) {
                if (this.ball.moveX === DIRECTION.RIGHT) this.ai.y += this.ai.speed / 1.5;
                else this.ai.y += this.ai.speed / 4;
            }
 
            // Handle ai (AI) wall collision
            if (this.ai.y >= this.canvas.height - this.ai.height) this.ai.y = this.canvas.height - this.ai.height;
            else if (this.ai.y <= 0) this.ai.y = 0;
 
            // Handle Player-Ball collisions
            if (this.ball.x - this.ball.width <= this.player.x && this.ball.x >= this.player.x - this.player.width) {
                if (this.ball.y <= this.player.y + this.player.height && this.ball.y + this.ball.height >= this.player.y) {
                    this.ball.x = (this.player.x + this.ball.width);
                    this.ball.moveX = DIRECTION.RIGHT;
                }
            }
 
            // Handle ai-ball collision
            if (this.ball.x - this.ball.width <= this.ai.x && this.ball.x >= this.ai.x - this.ai.width) {
                if (this.ball.y <= this.ai.y + this.ai.height && this.ball.y + this.ball.height >= this.ai.y) {
                    this.ball.x = (this.ai.x - this.ball.width);
                    this.ball.moveX = DIRECTION.LEFT;
                }
            }
        }
 
        // Handle the end of round transition
        // Check to see if the player won the round.
        if (this.player.score === rounds[this.round]) {
            // Check to see if there are any more rounds/levels left and display the victory screen if
            // there are not.
            if (!rounds[this.round + 1]) {
                this.over = true;
                setTimeout(function () { Pong.endGameMenu('Winner!'); }, 1000);
            } else {
                // If there is another round, reset all the values and increment the round number.
                this.color = this._generateRoundColor();
                this.player.score = this.ai.score = 0;
                this.player.speed += 0.5;
                this.ai.speed += 1;
                this.ball.speed += 1;
                this.round += 1;
            }
        }
        // Check to see if the ai/AI has won the round.
        else if (this.ai.score === rounds[this.round]) {
            this.over = true;
            setTimeout(function () { Pong.endGameMenu('Game Over!'); }, 1000);
        }
    },
 
    // Draw the objects to the canvas element
    draw: function () {
        // Clear the Canvas
        this.context.clearRect(
            0,
            0,
            this.canvas.width,
            this.canvas.height
        );
 
        // Set the fill style to black
        this.context.fillStyle = this.color;
 
        // Draw the background
        this.context.fillRect(
            0,
            0,
            this.canvas.width,
            this.canvas.height
        );
 
        // Set the fill style to white (For the paddles and the ball)
        this.context.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
 
        // Draw the Player
        this.context.fillRect(
            this.player.x,
            this.player.y,
            this.player.width,
            this.player.height
        );
 
        // Draw the Ai
        this.context.fillRect(
            this.ai.x,
            this.ai.y,
            this.ai.width,
            this.ai.height 
        );
 
        // Draw the Ball
        if (Pong._turnDelayIsOver.call(this)) {
            this.context.fillRect(
                this.ball.x,
                this.ball.y,
                this.ball.width,
                this.ball.height
            );
        }
 
        // Draw the net (Line in the middle)
        this.context.beginPath();
        this.context.setLineDash([7, 15]);
        this.context.moveTo((this.canvas.width / 2), this.canvas.height - 140);
        this.context.lineTo((this.canvas.width / 2), 140);
        this.context.lineWidth = 10;
        this.context.strokeStyle = '#ffffff';
        this.context.stroke();
 
        // Set the default canvas font and align it to the center
        this.context.font = '100px Courier New';
        this.context.textAlign = 'center';
 
        // Draw the players score (left)
        this.context.fillText(
            this.player.score.toString(),
            (this.canvas.width / 2) - 300,
            200
        );
 
        // Draw the paddles score (right)
        this.context.fillText(
            this.ai.score.toString(),
            (this.canvas.width / 2) + 300,
            200
        );
 
        // Change the font size for the center score text
        this.context.font = '30px Courier New';
 
        // Draw the winning score (center)
        this.context.fillText(
            'Round ' + (Pong.round + 1),
            (this.canvas.width / 2),
            35
        );
 
        // Change the font size for the center score value
        this.context.font = '40px Courier';
 
        // Draw the current round number
        this.context.fillText(
            rounds[Pong.round] ? rounds[Pong.round] : rounds[Pong.round - 1],
            (this.canvas.width / 2),
            100
        );
    },
 
    loop: function () {
        Pong.update();
        Pong.draw();
 
        // If the game is not over, draw the next frame.
        if (!Pong.over) requestAnimationFrame(Pong.loop);
    },
 
    listen: function () {
        var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

        // Adicione este trecho de código no início do seu script
        canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', function (event) {
            handleTouch(event.touches[0]);
        });

        canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', function (event) {
            handleTouch(event.touches[0]);
        });

// ...

var firstTouch = true;  // Adicione esta variável global para controlar o primeiro toque

// ...

function handleTouch(touch) {
    // Verifique a posição do toque em relação à altura da tela
    var metadeDaTela = canvas.height / 2;
    var toqueY = touch.clientY;

    // Move o jogador com base na posição do toque
    if (toqueY < metadeDaTela) {
        Pong.player.move = DIRECTION.UP;
    } else {
        Pong.player.move = DIRECTION.DOWN;
    }
}

canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', function (evento) {
    if (firstTouch) {
        Pong.running = true;
        window.requestAnimationFrame(Pong.loop);
        firstTouch = false;
    }

    handleTouch(evento.touches[0]);
});

canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', function (evento) {
    handleTouch(evento.touches[0]);
});

canvas.addEventListener('touchend', function () {
    Pong.player.move = DIRECTION.IDLE;
});

// ...




    },
 
    // Reset the ball location, the player turns and set a delay before the next round begins.
    _resetTurn: function (victor, loser) {
        this.ball = Ball.new.call(this, this.ball.speed);
        this.turn = loser;
        this.timer = (new Date()).getTime();
 
        victor.score++;
    },
 
    // Wait for a delay to have passed after each turn.
    _turnDelayIsOver: function () {
        return ((new Date()).getTime() - this.timer >= 1000);
    },
 
    // Select a random color as the background of each level/round.
    _generateRoundColor: function () {
        var newColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
        if (newColor === this.color) return Pong._generateRoundColor();
        return newColor;
    }
};
 
var Pong = Object.assign({}, Game);
Pong.initialize();
```

I tried to move the player with the touch, and I expected that when I pressed the player's position would follow the position of the touch that I set to be read